# AttributeError: 'TelnetConsole' object has no attribute 'port'

Tags: python, scrapy, telnet

I have just installed scrapy and was working through the linked tutorial (I have copied and pasted it and the code is fine): https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/overview.html

When I run scrapy in the command prompt I get the following error:
AttributeError: 'TelnetConsole' object has no attribute 'port'

Some other websites talk about editing the telnet.py documents but I am using scrapy 1.7.3 and my telnet.py file does not match.

I am quite new to coding. I can provide more information if needed.

Comment: That can onyl happen if the Scrapy engine is stopped before it is started. It sounds like a consecuence of a different, greater issue. Could you provide a minimal spider to reproduce this issue? (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You can also set `TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED=False` in your settings, and that specific error will no longer happen. But I bet your spider will not work as expected either.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set `TELNETCONSOLE_PORT = None` in `settings.py` and it should work if you do not need to use Telnet Console

EDIT:

You can also do `TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED=False` in `settings.py` to completely disable telnet console

Comment: In my settings.py file there was no TELNETCONSOLE_PORT, just a TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED.

Comment: If its not there, just write that setting